# WooCommerce hide some countries from customers but not for admin

Tags: woocommerce, country-codes

Hi see below code hiding countries for clients but not admin. I am using all ISO codes to hide and remove countries. This code does not contain the following countries (Austria, Denmark, Latvia, Estonia, Sweden, etc.) since I show them to clients in the checkout. If you want to add a country for a customer, you can remove the required line. If you need to disable, for example, Latvia for clients, add the line ( **unset($country["LV"]);** ) where LV is the ISO code. All ISO country code you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes).

> This solution allows you to limit the number of countries for a
> client, but the administrator can always select any country when
> editing a client order.

I use Code Snippet and turn this button ***Only run on site front-end***

```
function woo_remove_specific_country( $country ) {
unset($country["AF"]);
unset($country["AX"]);
unset($country["AL"]);
unset($country["DZ"]);
unset($country["AS"]);
unset($country["AD"]);
unset($country["AO"]);
unset($country["AI"]);
unset($country["AQ"]);
unset($country["AG"]);
unset($country["AR"]);
unset($country["AM"]);
unset($country["AW"]);
unset($country["AU"]);
unset($country["AZ"]);
unset($country["BS"]);
unset($country["BH"]);
unset($country["BD"]);
unset($country["BB"]);
unset($country["BY"]);
unset($country["BE"]);
unset($country["BZ"]);
unset($country["BJ"]);
unset($country["BM"]);
unset($country["BT"]);
unset($country["BO"]);
unset($country["BQ"]);
unset($country["BA"]);
unset($country["BW"]);
unset($country["BV"]);
unset($country["BR"]);
unset($country["IO"]);
unset($country["BN"]);
unset($country["BG"]);
unset($country["BF"]);
unset($country["BI"]);
unset($country["CV"]);
unset($country["KH"]);
unset($country["CM"]);
unset($country["CA"]);
unset($country["KY"]);
unset($country["CF"]);
unset($country["TD"]);
unset($country["CL"]);
unset($country["CN"]);
unset($country["CX"]);
unset($country["CC"]);
unset($country["CO"]);
unset($country["KM"]);
unset($country["CD"]);
unset($country["CG"]);
unset($country["CK"]);
unset($country["CR"]);
unset($country["CI"]);
unset($country["HR"]);
unset($country["CU"]);
unset($country["CW"]);
unset($country["CY"]);
unset($country["CZ"]);
unset($country["DJ"]);
unset($country["DM"]);
unset($country["DO"]);
unset($country["EC"]);
unset($country["EG"]);
unset($country["SV"]);
unset($country["GQ"]);
unset($country["ER"]);
unset($country["SZ"]);
unset($country["ET"]);
unset($country["FK"]);
unset($country["FO"]);
unset($country["FJ"]);
unset($country["FR"]);
unset($country["GF"]);
unset($country["PF"]);
unset($country["TF"]);
unset($country["GA"]);
unset($country["GM"]);
unset($country["GE"]);
unset($country["GH"]);
unset($country["GI"]);
unset($country["GR"]);
unset($country["GL"]);
unset($country["GD"]);
unset($country["GP"]);
unset($country["GU"]);
unset($country["GT"]);
unset($country["GG"]);
unset($country["GN"]);
unset($country["GW"]);
unset($country["GY"]);
unset($country["HT"]);
unset($country["HM"]);
unset($country["VA"]);
unset($country["HN"]);
unset($country["HK"]);
unset($country["HU"]);
unset($country["IS"]);
unset($country["IN"]);
unset($country["ID"]);
unset($country["IR"]);
unset($country["IQ"]);
unset($country["IE"]);
unset($country["IM"]);
unset($country["IL"]);
unset($country["IT"]);
unset($country["JM"]);
unset($country["JP"]);
unset($country["JE"]);
unset($country["JO"]);
unset($country["KZ"]);
unset($country["KE"]);
unset($country["KI"]);
unset($country["KP"]);
unset($country["KR"]);
unset($country["KW"]);
unset($country["KG"]);
unset($country["LA"]);
unset($country["LB"]);
unset($country["LS"]);
unset($country["LR"]);
unset($country["LY"]);
unset($country["LI"]);
unset($country["LU"]);
unset($country["MO"]);
unset($country["MK"]);
unset($country["MG"]);
unset($country["MW"]);
unset($country["MY"]);
unset($country["MV"]);
unset($country["ML"]);
unset($country["MT"]);
unset($country["MH"]);
unset($country["MQ"]);
unset($country["MR"]);
unset($country["MU"]);
unset($country["YT"]);
unset($country["MX"]);
unset($country["FM"]);
unset($country["MD"]);
unset($country["MC"]);
unset($country["MN"]);
unset($country["ME"]);
unset($country["MS"]);
unset($country["MA"]);
unset($country["MZ"]);
unset($country["MM"]);
unset($country["NA"]);
unset($country["NR"]);
unset($country["NP"]);
unset($country["NL"]);
unset($country["NC"]);
unset($country["NZ"]);
unset($country["NI"]);
unset($country["NE"]);
unset($country["NG"]);
unset($country["NU"]);
unset($country["NF"]);
unset($country["MP"]);
unset($country["NO"]);
unset($country["OM"]);
unset($country["PK"]);
unset($country["PW"]);
unset($country["PS"]);
unset($country["PA"]);
unset($country["PG"]);
unset($country["PY"]);
unset($country["PE"]);
unset($country["PH"]);
unset($country["PN"]);
unset($country["PT"]);
unset($country["PR"]);
unset($country["QA"]);
unset($country["RE"]);
unset($country["RO"]);
unset($country["RU"]);
unset($country["RW"]);
unset($country["BL"]);
unset($country["SH"]);
unset($country["KN"]);
unset($country["LC"]);
unset($country["MF"]);
unset($country["PM"]);
unset($country["VC"]);
unset($country["WS"]);
unset($country["SM"]);
unset($country["ST"]);
unset($country["SA"]);
unset($country["SN"]);
unset($country["RS"]);
unset($country["SC"]);
unset($country["SL"]);
unset($country["SG"]);
unset($country["SX"]);
unset($country["SK"]);
unset($country["SI"]);
unset($country["SB"]);
unset($country["SO"]);
unset($country["ZA"]);
unset($country["GS"]);
unset($country["SS"]);
unset($country["ES"]);
unset($country["LK"]);
unset($country["SD"]);
unset($country["SR"]);
unset($country["SJ"]);
unset($country["CH"]);
unset($country["SY"]);
unset($country["TW"]);
unset($country["TJ"]);
unset($country["TZ"]);
unset($country["TH"]);
unset($country["TL"]);
unset($country["TG"]);
unset($country["TK"]);
unset($country["TO"]);
unset($country["TT"]);
unset($country["TN"]);
unset($country["TR"]);
unset($country["TM"]);
unset($country["TC"]);
unset($country["TV"]);
unset($country["UG"]);
unset($country["UA"]);
unset($country["AE"]);
unset($country["GB"]);
unset($country["UM"]);
unset($country["US"]);
unset($country["UY"]);
unset($country["UZ"]);
unset($country["VU"]);
unset($country["VE"]);
unset($country["VN"]);
unset($country["VG"]);
unset($country["VI"]);
unset($country["WF"]);
unset($country["EH"]);
unset($country["YE"]);
unset($country["ZM"]);
unset($country["ZW"]);
   return $country; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'woo_remove_specific_country', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Is there a question hidden in there somewhere?

Comment: @itprorh66 LOL :)

Comment: `if ( ! is_admin() ) {` seems to be missing from your code, to only disable those countries in frontend…